# Hide command results in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to make a nice and clean batch file for an end user. I put @echo off but it still displays "operation completed successfully" when adding reg keys

Is there a way to hide the successful echo's also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect to `nul`

```
command > nul 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, that did the trick